# How to implement edge-to-edge with bottomsheet dialog android

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-gesture, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have an android application entirely based on immersive mode. I have managed to go edge-to-edge for the entire application but when I open a bottom sheet dialog with peek height of uptop 90% of the screen and a scrollview to  accomodate a long form. However, when I open the bottom sheet, there is a blank space at the bottom of the view which is exactly the size of the system navigation bar. Is there a way to remove that space and have the bottom sheet extend right upto the bottom of the screen?

Here's a snapshot of the bottom sheet fully expanded [image: bottom sheet screenshot]

**EDIT**: Added Example of My bottomsheet dialog class-

```
class MyBottomSheetDialog
constructor(val ctx: Context, val height: Int) :
    BaseDialog(ctx) {
...
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        binding.root.layoutParams.height = height
        binding.root.requestLayout()
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        window?.let {
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(
                it,false
            )
        }
        findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.container)?.fitsSystemWindows = false
        findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.coordinator)?.fitsSystemWindows = false
    }
...
}
```

And The base class is-

```
open class BaseDialog
constructor(
    private val dialogContext: Context) : BottomSheetDialog(dialogContext, style) {

override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        hideNavigation()
    }

    private fun hideNavigation() {
        window?.apply {
            val uiOptions: Int = decorView.systemUiVisibility
            val newUiOptions = uiOptions or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

            decorView.systemUiVisibility = newUiOptions

            setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your bottomSheetFragment

```kotlin
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog =
    object : BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme) {
        override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow()

            window?.let {
                WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(it, false)
            }

            findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.container)?.apply {
                fitsSystemWindows = false
                ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(this) { view, insets ->
                    insets.apply {
                        view.updatePadding(bottom = 0)
                    }
                }
            }

            findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.coordinator)?.fitsSystemWindows = false
        }
    }
```

in themes:

```xml
<item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
```

in styles:

```xml
  <style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is not working, the results are the same

Comment: @PriyaSindkar  can you provide a minimal example project to check it?!

Comment: Edited the question with the example

Comment: Note- The padding you mentioned doesn't solve the problem. And your solution works for the old navigation system bar but not for the new minimal navigation system line we have now (with gesture navigation on and 3-button navigation bar disabled)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Material Bottom Sheet doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheet.md#handling-insets-and-fullscreen):

> On API 21 and above the modal bottom sheet will be rendered fullscreen (edge to edge) if the navigation bar is transparent and `app:enableEdgeToEdge` is `true`. To enable edge-to-edge by default for modal bottom sheets, you can override `?attr/bottomSheetDialogTheme` like the below example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.*">
  ...
  <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.BottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.BottomSheetDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

in your theme file. See also [Google edge to edge training page](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge).